# Using Unity in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, ioc-container, unity2.0

I have Unity 2.0 working well within the App.xaml.cs to register and resolve within that class.

The question I have is regarding a best practice.

I have a number of User Controls and other classes that also need to resolve some of the same and new Interface <-> implementations.  The problem is theres no way to access the Unity container I created in the App.xaml.cs.

I cannot use constructor or property injection to pass on the container reference.

1. Just too many (its a large project)
2. The user controls are added via xaml
3. There are several very loosely
   related "modules" in the project
   that can share the same container
   config.

I would rather not re-create the container from a config file in each object that needs access to the container.

Any best practice suggestions when the same container is needed as a service in various "modules" of the same assembly?

Thanks.

Comment: You say "user controls are added via XAML": which parts are you aiming to inject? Usually you would possibly inject your View Models and definitely your "modules"/controllers/services.

Comment: I would like to using Unity to add the VM and to resolve a data provider or service provider in the ViewModels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe bringing together `Controls` and `IoC` is pain in the ... in the code at least. Probably somebody will argue but IMO the best practice to avoid this pain is `MVVM`. You will have viewModels which you can freely construct using `Unity` and inject everything you need into them. You will have views with bindings to viewModels with no reason to know anything abound inversion of control.

**UPDATE**: Based on comment:

App.xaml.cs:

```
    private void HandleStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var container = CreateContainer(); // create IoC container
       var mainViewModel = container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
        var shell = new Shell { DataContext = mainViewModel }; // main View
        MainWindow = shell;
        shell.Show();
    }
```

Shell XAML example:

```
<UserControl>
     <StackPanel>
          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ViewModel1}" />
          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ViewModel2}" />
          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ViewModel3}" />
     </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
     public ViewModel1 ViewModel1 { get; private set; }
     public ViewModel2 ViewModel2 { get; private set; }
     public ViewModel3 ViewModel3 { get; private set; }

     // this will be handled by IoC container
     public MainViewModel(ViewModel1 viewModel1, ViewModel2 viewModel2, ViewModel3 viewModel3)
    {
        ViewModel1 = viewModel1;
        ViewModel2 = viewModel2;
        ViewModel3 = viewModel3;
    }
```

In this way your views will be unaware of IoC and everything you want in viewModels will be successfully injected.

**UPDATE2** DataTemplating which brings `Views` and `ViewModels` together:

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
        <View1 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I am using MVVM - the views are implemented as User Controls. Currently the only thing I have in the View's code behind is creating the VM and adding it as the DataContext.  I would like to use Unity for this and for getting Data Providers in the ViewModel.  The MainWindow lays out a set of Views (each their own View+ViewModel).  I do not want to construct the MainWindow's elements programatically so how to I get each View+ViewModel in the MainWindow to share the Unity Container - am I missing something fundamental about the MVVM or Unity Patters?

Comment: @IUnknown, updated answer with some sample. The idea is that `MainWindow` should be also designed in `MVVM` style

Comment: In the Shell.XAML (main window) you are binding the VM to the Content - I thought I would bind the View to the Content element.  I do not see how I am bringing in the View.  What am I missing?

Comment: @IUnknown, the idea is to bind a ViewModel there. View is usually brought there by datatemplating. It means that somewhere (`app.xaml` for example) you will have: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel1}"><View1 /></DataTemplate>` for each view-viewmodel association.

Comment: Thank you - This nicely completes the Unity + MVVM picture for me.  I was struggling with how some of the pieces came together but now it works and better yet makes sense.  The only remaining question I have is where does `AutoMapperConfiguration` come from?  That line is not in my solution but still works.  Again thanks.

Comment: @IUnknown, oops that is part of our code, I will remove it. It is configuration for `AutoMapper` library, do you have it referenced?

Comment: You have just massively coupled your main view model with the child view models.  As I understand the whole concept of DI, this design seems to be a giant step backwards.